# Code the System.arraycopy function in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to implement the System.arraycopy function by myself. Would this be a valid way to implement the System.arraycopy method which is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) or do I overlook something? I would like that the function behaves the same as the System.arraycopy function.

```
public void copyArray(Integer[] arr1, int posArr1, Integer[] arr2, int posArr2, int length) {
    for (int i = posArr1; i < posArr1 + length; i++) {
        arr2[posArr2] = arr1[i];
        posArr2++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.arraycopy` is a native method meaning it is not implemented in Java

Comment: This question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What if arr2 is not long enough? what if length is longer than arr1? What if posArr1 or posArr2 is negative? Or length is zero or negative? What if arr1 or arr2 is null? So yes, you have overlooked a lot of things.